# Solving integrals using incomplete gamma function (upper gamma rule)

Tags: integral, function, calculus

I am attempting to integrate this function, ∫15x^(0.28) * e^(-0.21x) dx and am struggling with what techniques to apply. The lower boundary is 0 and the upper boundary is infinity. From research, I believe this is an example of an incomplete gamma function yet I am confused as how to solve this step by step. The image below is taken from an online integral calculator solver, yet the instructions skip most steps, therefore I am unsure how the upper gamma rule is actually applied. Any help would be greatly appreciated! [image]

Comment: This is not incomplete at all: it *is* a gamma function.  I would ignore the explanation, which is overly complicated, and just use basic Calculus.  All you need to do is change variables to $y = 0.21 x.$  The value will be elementary and simple to express -- far simpler than the nonsensical result provided by the calculator!

Comment: This site has math markup for equations, see https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1604/instructions-on-how-to-use-latex-on-crossvalidated/1605#1605  Please edit!